# How do i print out my functions in main in C?

Tags: c

I want to  Call all three functions from main
and Print the results in both the function definitions also  back in main
I couldn't find how to do this i already created all the functions and pointers i need .

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS    //to avoid scanf warning or error
int CalculateSum(int num1, int num2);
int CalculateProduct(int num1, int num2);
void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2, int*sumPtr, int *prodPtr);
int main(void)
{



}
int CalculateSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    int temp1;
    num1 = 1;
    num2 = 2;
    temp1 = num1 + num2;
    //printf("calculatesum value %d ", temp1);
     return (temp1); 

}
int CalculateProduct(int num1, int num2)
{
    num1 = 3;
        num2 = 4;
    int temp2;
    temp2 = num1*num2;
    printf("calc product  %d ", temp2);
        return temp2;

}


void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2, int*sumPtr, int *prodPtr)
{
    num1 = 5;
    num2 = 6;
    int temp3 = num1 + num2;
    sumPtr = &temp3;
    int temp4 = num1*num2;
    prodPtr = temp4;
    printf("calc sumptr  %d ", temp3);
    printf("Calc both prodptr  %d ", temp4);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's obvious you need a bit of help. Your functions are not quite what you would expect them to be. For starters you are passing `num1`, and `num2` to the functions. In order for that to happen, they must be declared in main. In addition to `num1` and `num2`, you need to declare variables to hold the return from the first two functions, say `sum` and `prod`. These will also be the same variable that you will pass as pointers to the CalculateBoth function so that their values are update and available in `main()`. A simple definition is in `main()` is all you need:

```
/* declare and initialize variables */
int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, sum = 0, prod = 0;
```

While there is nothing wrong with changing the value of a variable in a function, as you have all functions written, you completely defeat the purpose of passing `num1` and `num2` to the functions. It looks like you intend to pass the values of `num1` and `num2` to each of the functions, rather than changing the values in the functions. For example in `main()` you would expect to see:

```
/* CalculateSum */
n1 = 1, n2 = 2;
sum = CalculateSum (n1, n2);

/* CalculateProduct */
n1 = 3, n2 = 4;
prod = CalculateProduct (n1, n2);

/* CalculateBoth (passing pointer to have value back in main()) */
n1 = 5, n2 = 6;
CalculateBoth (n1, n2, &sum, &prod);
```

The remaining part of your task is to simply print the values (`sum`, `prod`, or `both`) in the function, and again in `main()` to insure you have successfully updated the values within the scope of the functions as well as `main()` (a function itself). The following shows the simple addition of the same print statements in both the functions and in main. Let me know if you have questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS    // I'll take your word for it...

int CalculateSum (int num1, int num2);
int CalculateProduct (int num1, int num2);
void CalculateBoth (int num1, int num2, int *sumPtr, int *prodPtr);

int main(void)
{
    /* declare and initialize variables */
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, sum = 0, prod = 0;

    /* CalculateSum */
    n1 = 1, n2 = 2;
    sum = CalculateSum (n1, n2);
    printf (" calculatesum value %d\n", sum);

    /* CalculateProduct */
    n1 = 3, n2 = 4;
    prod = CalculateProduct (n1, n2);
    printf (" calc product  %d\n", prod);

    /* CalculateBoth (passing pointer to have value back in main()) */
    n1 = 5, n2 = 6;
    CalculateBoth (n1, n2, &sum, &prod);
    printf(" calc both sumPtr   %d\n", sum);
    printf(" calc both prodPtr  %d\n", prod);


    return 0;
}

int CalculateSum (int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum;
    sum = num1 + num2;

    printf ("\n calculatesum value %d\n", sum);

    return sum; 
}

int CalculateProduct (int num1, int num2)
{
    int prod;
    prod = num1 * num2;
    printf ("\n calc product  %d\n", prod);

    return prod;
}

void CalculateBoth (int num1, int num2, int *sumPtr, int *prodPtr)
{
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    *sumPtr = sum;

    int prod = num1 * num2;
    *prodPtr = prod;

    printf("\n calc both sumPtr   %d\n", sum);
    printf(" calc both prodPtr  %d\n", prod);
}
```

**Output**

If you look closely at the code, you will see that the same thing is being printed both in the function and in main:

```
$ ./bin/fncinmain

 calculatesum value 3
 calculatesum value 3

 calc product  12
 calc product  12

 calc both sumPtr   11
 calc both prodPtr  30
 calc both sumPtr   11
 calc both prodPtr  30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define     _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     //to avoid scanf warning or error
int CalculateSum(int num1, int num2);
int CalculateProduct(int num1, int num2);
void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2, int*sumPtr, int *prodPtr);

int main(void) {
    int x = 5, y = 6, prod, sum;
    sum = CalculateSum(x, y);
    prod = CalulateProduct(x, y);
    printf("sum=%d Product=%d", x, y);
    printf("now calulate both at once");


    x = 4;
    y = 3;
    CalculateBoth(x, y, &sum, &prod);
    printf("%d %d", sum, prod);
    getch();
    return 0;

}

int CalculateSum(int num1, int num2) {
    int temp1;
    temp1 = num1 + num2;
    printf("calculatesum value %d ", temp1);
    return (temp1);

}

int CalculateProduct(int num1, int num2) {
    int temp2;
    temp2 = num1*num2;
    printf("calc product  %d ", temp2);
    return temp2;

}

void CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2, int* sumPtr, int *prodPtr) {
    int temp1, temp2;
    temp1 = num1 + num2;
    *sumPtr = temp1;
    temp2 = num1*num2;
    *prodPtr = temp2;
    printf("calc sumptr  %d ", temp1);
    printf("Calc both prodptr  %d ", temp2);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Return an Array from a function if you want to return multiple values.

```
int * CalculateBoth(int num1, int num2, int*sumPtr, int *prodPtr)
{
    num1 = 5;
    num2 = 6;
    int arr[2];
    arr[0] = num1 + num2;
    sumPtr = &temp3;
    arr[1] = num1*num2;
    prodPtr = temp4;
    printf("calc sumptr  %d ", temp3);
    printf("Calc both prodptr  %d ", temp4);
    return arr;
}
```

and then in main

```
int main()
{
int *p;
p=CalculateBoth(...);
printf("%d %d",p[0],p[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is going to work? What will happen when you attempt to assign a value to `p[1]` as it is written?